# Recursively set user permissions equal to group permissions without changing anything else

Tags: linux, bash, perl, permissions, find

Currently works for me (inspired from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/438082/find-files-where-group-permissions-equal-user-permissions)):

```
sudo find . \( \( -type d -o -type f \) ! -path ".git/*" \) -printf '%04m%p\0' | perl -n0e 'unless (/^.(.)\1/) {$p1=substr($_,1,1);$p2=substr($_,2,1);$p3=substr($_,3,1);$n=substr($_,4);system("sudo chmod $p1$p1$p3 $n");}'
```

But seems to be complex and very inefficient.

Thus, is it possible to achieve that in a more simple and/or efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/284428/copy-a-files-owner-permissions-to-group-permissions

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth
Thanks! :) The man page for chmod could be more verbose on this topic, imho.